# Syntax highlighting not working for iosApp

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I am following [the hands on tutorial on KMM](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Networking%20and%20Data%20Storage%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatfrom%20Mobile/09_Creating_the_iOS_application), and reached the point where I should write the iOS part of the app, however, when I head over to any of the `.swift` files, there's no syntax highlighting, the content appears as a plain text file.

[image]

- **Android Studio:** 4.1.1 (latest at the moment of writing)
- **KMM Plugin:** 0.2.0-release-65-Studio4.1 (latest at the moment of writing)

From what I see, the `iosApp` is not recognized at all as a module (like the `androidApp`, that has the name of the module highlighted via bold font), I suppose that is the issue.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use Xcode or (possibly) AppCode. Android Studio and the KMM plugin do not understand or highlight Swift code directly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I imported the `iosApp` into xcode and now I have syntax highlighting..., but the classes that are declared in the `shared` module are not visible, thats fine because I imported only the `iosApp`, so I tried to import the `shared` module  as well, but that seems is not possible, xcode does not recognize it as valid ios project structure. I am wondering, is there any documentation on how to work with KMM from ios/xcode side?

Comment: You can edit Kotlin from Xcode, but it won't be a great experience. Essentially you edit Kotlin in Android studio (or Intellij), and Swift in Xcode. We publish an Xcode plugin that does Kotlin source highlighting and lets you debug Kotlin code in Xcode, but there's no Kotlin code completion. It's not designed for editing so much as viewing and debugging: https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin

Comment: For an example project with everything connected, check out https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit. It's the "other" getting started project and docs :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into the same issue with AppCode not highlighting Swift, I just had to close the project and reopen it.